# How to check if a variables fits a custom type

Tags: python, python-3.x, custom-type, typed, python-3.10

I have this code:

```py
from typing import Tuple, Dict, List

CoordinatesType = List[Dict[str, Tuple[int, int]]]

coordinates: CoordinatesType = [
    {"coord_one": (1, 2), "coord_two": (3, 5)},
    {"coord_one": (0, 1), "coord_two": (2, 5)},
]
```

I would like to check at runtime if my variable fits my custom type definition.
I was thinking on something like:

```py
def check_type(instance, type_definition) -> bool:
    return isinstance(instance, type_definition)
```

But obviously `isinstance` is not working.
I need to check this at runtime, what would be the correct way to implement it?

Comment: What you are asking isn't a python runtime type check -- that is, `List[Dict[str, Tuple[int, int]]]` *isn't a real type*, it is a *type annotation* that can be checked for correctness statically using something like `mypy`. To check `coordinates` you would have to implement the logic yourself.

Comment: Try to use `Typeguard`,https://typeguard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Try to use `Typeguard`:https://typeguard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html#using-type-checker-functions

### Example:

#### code:

```
from typeguard import check_type
from typing import Tuple, Dict, List
coordinates = [
    {"coord_one": (1, 2), "coord_two": (3, 5)},
    {"coord_one": (0, 1), "coord_two": (2, 5)},
]
try:
    check_type('coordinates', coordinates, List[Dict[str, Tuple[int, int]]])
    print("type is correct")
except TypeError as e:
    print(e)

coordinates = [
    {"coord_one": (1, 2), "coord_two": ("3", 5)},
    {"coord_one": (0, 1), "coord_two": (2, 5)},
]
try:
    check_type('coordinates', coordinates, List[Dict[str, Tuple[int, int]]])
    print("type is correct")
except TypeError as e:
    print(e)
```

#### result:

```
type is correct
type of coordinates[0]['coord_two'][0] must be int; got str instead
```